# Seeing which elements are available on the page when using Capybara and RSpec

Tags: testing, rspec, capybara

I am using RSpec and Capybara to do testing. I am using binding.pry to test out some lines of code; however, Capybara can not find the element that I need. Is there a command that will list the html elements that are available for me to use as selectors?

FYI, this is my first question and I tried to research as much as possible before asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in method to do that, however depending on which driver you're using you can get something like what you're asking for.  If using one of the real browser drivers that has support for the :scope pseudo class you can do something like

```
find("form.***").all(':scope > *').map {|el| el['outerHTML']}
```

if no :scope support in the real browser you can use xpath

```
find("form.***").all(:xpath, './/child::*').map {|el| el['outerHTML']}
```

If using the default rack-test driver you can do something like

```
find("form.***").all('> *').map {|el| el.native.to_s }
```

Those will give you an array of the html elements that are children of your initial find and let you see what classes/attributes/etc they have, and can obviously be turned into a method to make easier to use.  While this is possible, please note that specifying every ancestor in a selector when using Capybara can lead to brittle tests, if you ever make a change to the page, and you're usually better off using the capybara provided selectors with locators to find specific elements to interact with whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could try printing out `page.body` in your pry session. It will print a snapshot of the DOM of the current document.

Capybara documentation might be a little tricky to read. What you need to know is that `page` [is equivalent to `Capybara.current_session`](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/dsl.rb#L46) . `Capybara::Session` instance [has the method `body`](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/session.rb#L152), that holds a snapshot of the DOM.

Comment: That doesn't really accomplish what I was asking about. My resolution for the time being is to page.find("form.*** div.*** button.***).click

What I was trying to see was if I did a within("form.***) I could then see which elements were available for me to choose from. Essentially it would print out a list like div.***, div.*** and then from there I could choose the one I wanted and keep drilling down until I found the selector I wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the info tho!